# How is the Hero Merit calculated?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Since the [1.2.0 update](http://nintendoeverything.com/fire-emblem-heroes-update-out-now-version-1-2-0/) of the game, heroes now gain Hero Merit during the battle, which are later transformed into Hero Feathers. But I am not sure to understand how those points are awarded for each characters in your party.

How many points are awarded depending on a specific executed action during a game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [gamepedia](http://feheroes.gamepedia.com/Hero_Merit), a hero will get between 0-5 Hero Merits per battle.

> Hero Merit can be obtained by heroes who successfully survive and complete a battle. **The hero will then gain anywhere from 0 to 5 Hero Merit depending on the difficulty of the battle based on the number of enemies on the map, the enemy level, and the enemy rarity.**

As of right now, an *exact* formula is not known, however, [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FireEmblemHeroes/comments/654gk5/hero_merit_math/) explains how to get over 500 total Hero Merits a day, as clearing the Tenth Stratum in the Training Tower with 4 5 star Heroes apparently *always* awards 4.60 Hero Merit per character.

> Bringing 4 5 Star Lvl 40 Units into Tenth Stratum gives each unit 4.60 Merit to each. Thanks to the 99 stamina cap its more plausible to use all of the natural stamina given each day.
>
> ((24 Hours x 60 Minutes)/5 Regen Timer) = 288 StaminaPerDay
>
> That lets us do the Tenth Stratum 32 times a day. Assuming no deaths, each time you do Tenth Stratum you gain 147.2 Merit for each unit or a total of 588.8.
>
> It will take approximately 13.58 days to get 4 units to 2000 Hero Merit each. Meaning an average day of Tenth Stratum gives 589 feathers.